# Differences Regarding created vs extended ember controllers; their naming conventions and scope

Tags: ember.js

Right now I'm hitting a wall in my understanding of ember controllers.

I have a model "batch" that is never the main model of a route or controller. I want to be able to access all the objects of this class via an arraycontroller from any route in my app.

Therefore I created an empty batches controller which is nothing more than

```
// controllers/batches.js

App.BatchesController = Ember.ArrayController.create();
```

Then I created a batches initializer which contains

```
// initializers/batches.js

Ember.Application.initializer({
  name: 'batch',
  after: 'preload',

  initialize: function (container, application) {
    var store;
    store = container.lookup('store:main');

    store.find('batch', { state: "uploaded" }).then(function (batches) {
      App.BatchesController.set('content', batches.content);
    });
  }
});
```

Note that after a lot of heartache, I figured out that this setup only worked with a capital  B in batches controller although a coworker had read that this should infact be lower case and I have no idea why either of those two things would be important.

This setup basically works until I need to reference the content of this controller in another controller. Here is the second controller:

```
// controllers/inbox.js

App.InboxController = App.LibraryController.extend({
  needs: ['application', 'batches'],


  hasActiveBatches: function () {
    // do something here
    this.get('controllers.batches') ==> TypeError: undefined is not a function
  }.property('controllers.batches')

});
```

Instead I can only access the content of the batches controller via "App.BatchesController"
which is of no use for creating a computed property.

I realize that something is fundamentally different about my controller because it was manually created instead of extended and instantiated by ember but I really don't understand what the difference is or how it affects my options for accessing it's content.

Any clarification for what is going on behind the scenes here and possibly a better pattern to use here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Controller classes should be capitalized. They shouldn't be created, just extended. When using needs you should specify it in camelCase.
2. When ember creates a controller it keeps track of it and makes it available to other controllers via needs, if you create it, it doesn't know about it.
3. Using an initializer is weird here, it'd make more sense in the application controller to get the batches and set up the controller.

I'd just do it like this, create an array, and attach it to all of the controllers.  Then you could just access the property right on the controller without having to use needs or anything like that (You could also inject it on all of the routes if you wanted).

```
Ember.Application.initializer({
  name: 'batch',
  after: 'preload',

  initialize: function (container, application) {
    var store = container.lookup('store:main'),
        batchesArr = [];
    application.register("my:batches", batchesArr, {instantiate: false});
    application.inject("controller", "batches", "my:batches");
    store.find('batch', { state: "uploaded" }).then(function (batches) {
      batchesArr.pushObjects(batches.toArray());
    });
  }
});
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nobima/8/edit

Example of *everyone has the same collection, one updates, they all update*: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nobima/9/edit?html,js,output

Example using controllerFor: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nobima/11/edit

Comment: This seems much more sane. I'm going to try to integrate this into my code and report back.

Comment: 2 questions:

One thing I should have bone more clear about: I need to be able to add batches to what ever is keeping track of them after initialization and have all of my controllers be aware of additions. I'm guessing this is not possible using injection via an initializer? If so, how?

Also you said "Using an initializer is weird here" but then used an initializer in the example so I was confused by that. I agree that using the application controller seems like a good solution but it already has a model. How would I give it this second model that it can pass around?

Comment: Yes, I was a little torn in the suggestion.  Generally using the needs pattern is the taught and recommended pattern.  But at the same time, there would be a lot less code by using the initializer in this case.  You can definitely add/remove from the array and have it update everywhere, just use `addObject`/`pushObject` on the batches property.  You can always do `this.controllerFor` from within a route to grab a different controller.  Then you could apply a model to that controller.  This avoids you manually creating the controller and allows you to share

Comment: I tossed up two more examples

Comment: My second comment was actually incorrect. I was able to push to the batchesArr and have that state persist globally which means this solution works perfectly for my use case. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: By the way the jsbins are fantastic. Very high quality and they definitely illustrate the concepts. Thanks again for putting so much effort into the response.